# Selecting in JQ with Contains in a Array

Tags: json, select, jq

I want to select the particular item from the array using `contains` and get the first item using JQ.

JQ:

```
.amazon.items[] | select(.name | contains ("shoes"))
```

JSON:

```
{
  "amazon": {
    "activeitem": 2,
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "harry potter",
        "state": "sold"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "adidas shoes",
        "state": "in inventory"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "watch",
        "state": "returned"
      },{
        "id": 4,
        "name": "adidas shoes",
        "state": "in inventory"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Expected Result:

```
{
  "activeitem": 2,
  "item": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "adidas shoes",
    "state": "in inventory"
  }
}
```

Actual :

Tried various options like but not getting the Intended response .

1. `.amazon.items[] |  select(.name | contains ("shoes"))`
2. `.amazon.items |  select(.[].name | contains ("shoes")) | .[0]`

Also when I try to combine `activeitem` and `item`, I get something like this, which is also wrong.

```
{
  "activeitem": 2,
  "item": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "adidas shoes",
    "state": "in inventory"
  }
},
  {
  "activeitem": 2,
  "item": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "adidas shoes",
    "state": "in inventory"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To edit "in-place" you could write:

```
.amazon
| .items |= map(select(.name | contains ("shoes")))[0]
```

If you really want to change the name 'items' to 'item', you could tweak the above as follows:

```
.amazon
| .item = (.items | map(select(.name | contains ("shoes")))[0])
| del(.items)
```

Comment: Hi Peak, Can i do this same as transformation to new Object. Here i have trimmed the JSON , there are lot of other fields in input json which i dont need in output. I was able to remove them by using del, but that is becoming a big list.

Comment: @Aksanth - Sorry, I don't understand the new question. Maybe you should create a new Question?  Please don't forget to follow the [mcve] guidelines.